# Does BitLocker with SED require a TPM?

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

Assuming a BIOS that supports SED (Self Encrypting Drive) hard drives, and given that Windows 8 will use hardware encryption like SED if the disk has it, does BitLocker still require a TPM to avoid using USB? This regards a standalone laptop not part of a domain.

Comment: According to [this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c49b6e3e-a965-4b1b-bcf4-4e954ca78015/bitlocker-with-self-encrypting-drives), BitLocker doesn't require a TPM to be used with SED.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can setup bitlocker (with SED) without TPM. But...
**if you dont want to use USB and if you dont want to enter preboot password then TPM is required**. TPM is required to save keys that require for SED to unlock. SED must be OPAL complied to work with TPM.

Comment: do you have an references for this answer?

Comment: There is no single page about this. I have read lots of sources, most of them from "Trusted Computing Group". TPM and OPAL both have standarts from Trusted Computing Group. One of these link is http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/commonly_asked_questions_and_answers_on_selfencrypting_drives
another link http://www.flashmemorysummit.com/English/Collaterals/Proceedings/2012/20120821_S103A_Thibadeau.pdf

Comment: Maybe preboot passcode is required in both case (with TPM or w/o TPM), I gess with TPM hard drive is bound to motherboard. Maybe you dont have to use preboot passcode with bitlocker.

Comment: password is not required when booting with  the usb key inserted and no tpm